# Idiomatic way in Svelte to do two way binding with an intermediate transformation

Tags: svelte

Two way binding is great and elegant in Svelte, but a recurrent situation I've come across is needing two way binding with an intermediate transformation that converts types or does some kind of clean up. For example:

- Binding to a select component's prop `value` that has the form `{value, label}`, but its parent just handles a value
- Type conversions, where a `<input type=text>` is also input for some other type (Number, date, custom one), or an input to edit an object as JSON that could also be changed from the outside.

**My question is: Which is a good, idiomatic and simple way of solving this pattern in Svelte?**

The best reusable solution I've found so far has been to create a *store factory* for one-to-one transformations that returns two stores, `a` and `b` which you can then use and bind to other components:

[Example: play with REPL here](https://svelte.dev/repl/5e843b6b99ac4d20880fc88f35d9e5fb?version=3.48.0)

```svelte
// App.svelte
<script>
    import oneToOne from './oneToOne.js'
    
    const f = x => JSON.stringify({x});
    const fInv = x => {try{return JSON.parse(x).x} catch(err){return NaN}};
    
    let [a, b] = oneToOne(13, f, fInv); 
</script>

A: <input bind:value={$a}/>
B: <input bind:value={$b}/>
```

```svelte
// oneToOne.js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

const identity = x => x;

export default function oneToOne(val, f = identity, fInv = identity) {
    let fInvB = val;
    let fA = f(val);
    
    const A = writable(fInvB);
    const B = writable(fA);
    
    B.subscribe((b) => {    
        if(fA !== b && !(Number.isNaN(fA) && Number.isNaN(b))) {            
            fInvB = fInv(b);
            fA = b;         
            A.set(fInvB)
        }
    }); 
    
    A.subscribe((a) => {        
        if(fInvB !== a && !(Number.isNaN(fInvB) && Number.isNaN(a))) {          
             fA = f(a); 
             fInvB = a;         
             B.set(fA)
        }
    }); 

    return [A, B];
}
```

Does this make sense? Am I missing a simpler way of doing this or avoiding this complexity altogether?

Comment: There are also issues on GitHub about this problem: [#3937](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/3937), [#7265](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/7265)

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to [@H.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546730/h-b) I realized I had missed a [comment on this github issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/3937#issuecomment-695124194) with what I think is the most simple/small/idiomatic way of coding this case that I've seen so far.

The idea I had missed: To avoid the circular dependency issue with in/out conversions, just declare `in`/`out` (or `f(x)`, `fInv(x)`) with the assigment in them, and then invoke them reactively. The original example would end up like this:

```svelte
<script>
    let a = 13, b;
    const f = x => b = JSON.stringify({x});
    const fInv = x => {try{a = JSON.parse(x).x} catch(err){a = NaN}};
    
    $: f(a);
    $: fInv(b); 
</script>

A: <input bind:value={a}/>
B: <input bind:value={b}/>
```

[Full REPL here](https://svelte.dev/repl/fce6e30f34ee49c1b9674731dc40b395?version=3.48.0)

That's it! No stores or helpers needed, with the same or less verbosity. I initially thought there might be a reentrancy problem/infinite loop if `f(fInv(x)) !== x`, but If I understand correctly it works because Svelte never executes a reactive statement more than once in the same tick.

**EDIT:** There is no infinite loop, but there's an ugly side: depending on the order of the reactive statements, assignment in one of the two directions is going to trigger a reentrant update of the variable triggering the update ([known issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/7359)). That can be annoying in some cases, when the transformation is asymetrical. See more below

**Caveat/Interesting corner case**

In my original example and proposed solution, when the JSON input is edited to an invalid JSON, `fInv` returns `NaN` for `a`, but it does not propagates back to `b` and the JSON input (if so, it would be `{x: null}`), so you can keep typing until a valid json is reached. This is nice because it allows a "smoother" json text editing, but it creates an inconsistent state between the two inputs.

Whether this is desirable or not, this answer does not always behaves the same way: [The original `oneToOne.js`](https://svelte.dev/repl/5e843b6b99ac4d20880fc88f35d9e5fb?version=3.48.0) explicitely prevented the store update "reentrancy", so if a non number is typed in the "binary bonus track" the `NaN` does not propagate back. But in [this answer´s implementation](https://svelte.dev/repl/fce6e30f34ee49c1b9674731dc40b395?version=3.48.0), dependening on the reactive statements order the same actions can trigger a reentrancy, propagating `NaN` to the original binary input.

Comment: I am not a fan of this approach because it uses multiple dependent reactive statements which makes it harder to track what is going on and it creates more variables in scope that are only there for the transform. In my answer there only is ever one additional variable in scope that fully encapsulates its transform.

Comment: It is true what you point about the variables, but I'm not sure it outweights having a dependency, two extra imports and store variables around.  However, I do agree with the fact that reactive statements pose some issues: the order in which you write them determines whether there is a single reentrant update after updating A or B, depending on the order. Thats the only part that I don't really like...

Comment: It doesn't make sense if variables are nested inside of HTML. Svelte uses very nested. For instance I want to use column index `{#if parseInt(cell)}
              {parseInt(cell) * $FilteredColumnsProcess[columnIndex]}
              {/if}`

Answer (score 4):

Defining two stores at the same time seems a bit unnecessary, depending on intended semantics. It could also be approached as there being one source and a derived store.

```html
<script>
    import { transformed } from './transform-store.js';
    import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

    const number = writable(13);
    const json = transformed(number, {
        in: value => JSON.stringify({ x: value }),
        out: value => { try { return JSON.parse(value).x; } catch(err) { return NaN; } },
    });
</script>

Number to JSON:
<input bind:value={$number} type="number" />
<input bind:value={$json} />
```

`transform-store.js`

```js
import { derived } from 'svelte/store';

export function transformed(store, options) {
    const identity = x => x;
    const transformIn = options.in ?? identity;
    const transformOut = options.out ?? identity;
    
    const { subscribe } = derived(store, $store => transformIn($store));
    const set = value => store.set(transformOut(value));
    
    return { subscribe, set };
}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/09e1b9d60154478d9006331476752a58?version=3.48.0)

The transformed store is essentially a derived store augmented to be writable by defining its own `set` function that modifies the source store.

---

This can also be done without stores by using reactive statements and property descriptors:

```html
<script>
    function transformed(get, set) {
        const o = {};
        Object.defineProperty(o, 'value', { get, set });
        
        return o;
    }

    let number = 13;
    $: json = transformed(
        () => JSON.stringify({ x: number }),
        value => { try { number = JSON.parse(value).x; } catch(err) { number = NaN; } },    
    )
</script>

Number to JSON:
<input bind:value={number} type="number" />
<input bind:value={json.value} />
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/eb2220af638b45fc9622a5b8f097e9b2?version=3.48.0)

Ideally there would just be built-in language support for this, though.

Comment: Great, your `transform-store.js` is definitely a clever improvement over mine! The get/set version, however, doesn't feel very idiomatic to me. I had also missed one of the github issue you mentioned, and there was a very interesting and simple answer I missed there without using stores! I'll reproduce it in an answer of its own because I think it is worth it. In all versions, however, there is an interesting corner case when transformations are asymetrical (NaN case), where my first example does not have reentrancy, but other do. Not sure which would be a reasonable semantic.

Comment: @Hutzz The get/set is just a workaround. As noted this should just be supported by Svelte directly to obsolete the use of stores, multiple reactive statements or the get/set wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

The feature can also be implemented using **unidirectional data flow**:
(Events Up, Data Down)

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/310bb27194784dafa62d2f9861eb1b4e?version=3.48.0)

```html
<script>
let value = 13

function setA(string) {
  value = parseInt(value, 10);
}

function setB(json) {
  value = JSON.parse(json)?.x
}
</script>

A: <input value="{value}" on:input={ (e) => setA(e.target.value) }/>
B: <input value={{ x: value }} on:input={ (e) => setB(e.target.value) }/>
```

i.m.h.o this is the "simpler way of doing this"
It makes the flow of the change explicit and predictable.

If the value is not the same, the variable should not be "bound" to that value. (using stores with asymmetrical getter and setter feels hacky to me)

It does require the child component to emit an onchange event of some kind.

The extra "wiring" you write can also add fine grained control ([REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/6289bbdcef3040e48bb195cea5387681?version=3.48.0)), but the additional code also increases the possibility for bugs.

Comment: It's a super valid option, but it obviously defeats the purpose of taking adavantage of Svelte's two way bindings. As you correctly pointed out, that implies adding `onchange` events to custom components which is part of the verbosity I was trying to avoid (even though it is debatable whether it is a good idea to have custom input components that solely rely on the implicit data flow of binding its value).